# Individually select the last X rows from an SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, date, twitter

I have a database that stores Twitter posts using the Twitter API - under the headings id (stored as tag:search.twitter.com,2005:195795633834176512), author, time, text - and I have a page which prints out the last 7 days worth of posts from that database. 
Some days it can be 10-20 posts for the last 7, some times it can be 100-200.
I've been trying to integrate a news ticker into the page, so each post appears in a box, then fades out to be replaced by another post, meaning that instead of 200 lines you have one that iterates through:

```
  <div id="news1">
            <h3>Stackoverflow</h3>
            <!-- Displaying News Module --> 

            <div class="news-container" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: relative; height: 1207px; ">
<!-- ul id="news-scroller" -->
<ul style="left: 207px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-       bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; top: 0px; ">

<li style="display: list-item; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; height: 69px; ">
<div style="padding-bottom: 5px;">


<!-- Displaying News Module -->

<?php
require_once 'db-functions.inc.php' ; //custom database functions

echo "<ul class=\"twitter_feed\">\n" ;
$result = dbQuery("SELECT * FROM `HASH` WHERE text LIKE '%stackoverflow%' AND `hidden` != 'y' AND from_unixtime(time) > date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day) ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($row = dbGetRow($result)) {
$text = stripslashes($row['text']);
$time = $row['time'];
$author = stripslashes($row['author']); 
echo "  <li><span class=\"twitter_time\">".date('M j, Y, g:i a',$time)."</span> &middot; $author: $text</li>\n" ;
}
echo "</ul>\n" ;

?>
```

However, this just outputs the last 7 days as one lump, rather than one at a time:
http://sanctuary-westminster.org/server/scroll.php

The question is how to individually output the last entries (the ones with the largest time stamp) as "news items", so last post, penultimate post, etc. 
It won't be a fixed number of entries, one 7 day could be 10, another 200, so I'm finding it tricky to write the echo and iteration.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you looking for some solution [like on Facebook](http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/tag/facebook-scroll-data-load-jquery/), where you browse up new entries, or you need [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination#Pagination_in_Web_content_.28HTML.2C_ASP.2C_PHP.2C_and_others.29)?

Comment: I would do this differently, use ajax to get tweets and then show it one by one using js

Comment: I haven't used AJAX before (or really had any dealings with it); my code was trying to fit PHP code I'd written into someone elses scrolling code, so thank you for the suggestion, it's given my an idea how to do this differently.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the best way would be to use AJAX as stated in a comment, but the simplest way, using code that you have already written, would be to dump the array of posts from the database into a javascript array, and then loop through the javascript array with your news ticker. You could do this like:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var tweets = [""]; 
                                      var author = [""]; 
                                      var times = [""]; ';

while ($row = dbGetRow($result))
{
    echo "tweets.push('$row[text]'); 
          author.push('$row[author]'); 
          times.push('$row[times];"; 
}

echo '</script>';
```

then you can loop through the array's with javascript to display their info in your news ticker one at a time.

Edit: i fixed the initial var assignments, as suggested in the comment below.

Comment: Did you mean `author = [""];` and `var times = [""];` rather than `var author[""];` and `var times[""];` ?

Comment: Having looked at AJAX vs PHP (as [someone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525730/ajax-vs-php-for-dynamic-web-pages) else said: "PHP is creating the content dynamically whereas one can say that Ajax is loading the content dynamically.") I'm going to look at AJAX closer as it looks to be a better tool for what I want